# Absolute positioning a FlatList item react-native

Tags: animation, react-native, absolute, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to make an animation inside a FlatList in react-native.

Flat List

```
--------
 item1
--------
 item2
--------
 item3
--------
```

As soon as I press the item2 the FlatList will look like this:

```
--------
 item1
--------
 empty
--------
 item3
```

And on top of the FlatList (starting from the empty space) it will be the item2 expanding to full screen height, not allowing item1 and item3 to move in the list.

Does anyone have an idea if this can be done using react-native?

I already tried this using absolute positioning with zIndex but nothing seems to work.

Here is my FlatList item

```
<Animated.View style={[ { height: this.state.height }, this.state.pressed ? { position: 'absolute', top:0, bottom:0, left:0, right:0, zIndex: 1000 } : 
{} ]}>
  <Text>Absolute expandable FlatList item</Text>
</Animated.View>
```

The FlatList item has style absolute because in react every element has relative positioning by default.

I did a trick without absolute positioning, using scrollToIndex to move the element at the top of the list and then position it as absolute. But this will make the item3 disapear from the screen while the item2 height is expanding.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this can be having an extra component that has an absolute positioning and opacity 0. When you press on an item you can turn pressed item's opacity to 0 and then render the extra component with the info from the pressed item and then you can give the desired animation. This way pressed item's row will be still filled but seen as empty. If this extra component be inside the `FlatList` item it can't go out of row's boundaries (as far as I know). You might need to calculate position of the pressed item to start animation of the extra component from.

Comment: If I'll do this then the animation won't we fluid. I get a flicker when changing states because the "modal" component outside, will re-render on each item tap. Will display for a fraction of a second the old element, or the empty one, if I reset it before closing it, and then changing state happens and re-render the component. I can play with it to change the zIndex and/or opacity only after the state is changed but that won't be fuid.

Comment: I marked the response as correct one because indeed you can achieve what I asked, but the flicker is there when rerender is triggered by the state change, on both items (FlatList item and external Item used on top of everything). I'm choosing the initial solution: FlatList.scrollToIndex + ItemList Animation + FlatList.scrollEnabled = false + itemList.scrollEnabled = true.

Comment: I know this does not fit your use case but I made this snack that might be useful to some. https://snack.expo.io/@n1ru4l/listview-2-fullscreen